# Why does 'this' inside String.prototype refer to an object type, not a string type?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to extend string to provide a hash of itself. I am using the Node.js crypto library.

I extend string like this:

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
    return getHash(this);
};
```

and I have a `getHash` function that looks like this:

```
function getHash(testString) {
    console.log("type is" + typeof(testString));
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
    hash.update(testString);
    var result = hash.digest('hex');
    return result;
}
```

The function works fine when called directly, as in

```
var s = "Hello world";
console.log(getHash(s));
```

but when I try:

```
var s = "ABCDE";
console.log(s.hashCode());
```

the method call fails.  It appears that `this` in the `String.prototype.hashCode` is identified as an object when `crypto.hash.update` is called, but a string is expected.  I thought that `this` inside `String.prototype` would be the string itself, but for some reason it looks like an object to `getHash()`.  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` can’t be of a primitive type outside of [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), so it becomes a `String` [wrapper type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects), which doesn’t behave like a primitive string at all (particularly as far as `typeof` and equality – both strict and loose – go). You can cast it:

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function () {
    return getHash('' + this);
};
```

where `'' +` is used to cast any value to a primitive string. (`String(this)` also works, if you feel that it’s clearer.)

You can also go into strict mode, where things *just make sense*:

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function () {
    'use strict';
    return getHash(this);
};
```

Comment: I would just go with 'use strict', but still leave a comment explaining why it is required. It's likely that most maintainers won't know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a method on a variable of primitive type, so-called **auto-boxing** is taken place. That process wraps a primitive value into corresponding object, for example `'asdf'` to `new String('asdf')`. Because technically primitive values don't have *methods* and *properties*, they are hosted in object prototypes. With auto-boxing you could call methods on primitive values. And within a method, `this` is always the **object** that has that method.

If you want to access the primitive value in a method, you could either pass it as an argument, or as you would like, retrieve primitive value from `this`. For example:

```
var str = new String('asdf') // String {0: "a", 1: "s", 2: "d", 3: "f", length: 4, formatUnicorn: function, truncate: function, splitOnLast: function, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "asdf"}
String(str) // 'asdf'

var num = new Number(123) // Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 123}
Number(num) // 123

var bool = new Boolean(true) // Boolean {[[PrimitiveValue]]: true}
Boolean(bool) // true
```